# Optimization of XSLT using Identity Transform

Tags: xml, xslt

I recently ran across the following stock ticker XML feed:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<BloombergOutput>
  <BloombergOutput CreatedUtc="2011-08-11T20:40:50.8851936Z">
    <Instruments>
      <Instrument Symbol="BLL">
        <Fields>
          <Field1 Name="LastPrice">
            <Value>35.550000</Value>
          </Field1>
          <Field2 Name="NetChangeOneDay">
            <Value>+1.550000</Value>
          </Field2>
          <Field3 Name="LastCloseDate">
            <Value>08/11/2011</Value>
          </Field3>
          <Field4 Name="LastClosePrice">
            <Value>35.550000</Value>
          </Field4>
          <Field5 Name="UpdateDate">
            <Value>08/11/2011</Value>
          </Field5>
          <Field6 Name="UpdateTime">
            <Value>16:15:03</Value>
          </Field6>
          <Field7 Name="LongName">
            <Value>Ball Corp</Value>
          </Field7>
          <Field8 Name="Name">
            <Value>BALL CORP</Value>
          </Field8>
          <Field9 Name="PriceSource">
            <Value>US</Value>
          </Field9>
          <Field10 Name="SymbolType">
            <Value>Common Stock</Value>
          </Field10>
        </Fields>
      </Instrument>
    </Instruments>
  </BloombergOutput>
</BloombergOutput>
```

I wanted to use XSLT to transform this feed into something that didn't have the unnecessary tag nesting, had more descriptive element names, and truncated overly long numbers so they only had two numbers after the decimal point.  Here's the XSLT I came up with:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
  xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
  <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="no" indent="yes"/>
  <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

  <!-- Identity Transform, modified to begin at the Instruments element -->
  <xsl:template match="BloombergOutput/BloombergOutput/Instruments/@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

  <!-- For each instrument, we grab the Symbol attribute and work on each child element -->
  <xsl:template match="Instrument">
    <Instrument>
      <Symbol><xsl:value-of select="@Symbol" /></Symbol>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="Fields/*" mode="fields" />
    </Instrument>
  </xsl:template>

  <!-- For each child field, we create a newly-named one and give it a value -->
  <xsl:template match="node()" mode="fields">

    <xsl:variable
      name="FieldName"
      select="@Name" />
    <xsl:variable
        name="Value"
        select="Value" />

    <xsl:element name="{$FieldName}">
      <xsl:choose>
        <!-- For these fields, we only want to preserve to spots after the decimal point -->
        <xsl:when test="$FieldName='LastPrice' or $FieldName='NetChangeOneDay' or $FieldName='LastClosePrice'">
          <xsl:value-of select="concat(substring-before($Value, '.'), '.', substring(substring-after($Value, '.'), 1, 2))" />
        </xsl:when>
        <xsl:otherwise>
          <xsl:value-of select="$Value" />
        </xsl:otherwise>
      </xsl:choose>
    </xsl:element>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

...which produces this output:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<BloombergOutput>
  <BloombergOutput>2011-08-11T20:40:50.8851936Z
    <Instruments>
      <Instrument>
        <Symbol>BLL</Symbol>
        <LastPrice>35.55</LastPrice>
        <NetChangeOneDay>+1.55</NetChangeOneDay>
        <LastCloseDate>08/11/2011</LastCloseDate>
        <LastClosePrice>35.55</LastClosePrice>
        <UpdateDate>08/11/2011</UpdateDate>
        <UpdateTime>16:15:03</UpdateTime>
        <LongName>Ball Corp</LongName>
        <Name>BALL CORP</Name>
        <PriceSource>US</PriceSource>
        <SymbolType>Common Stock</SymbolType>
      </Instrument>
    </Instruments>
  </BloombergOutput>
</BloombergOutput>
```

Although this is nearly what I want, there are some issues:

1. The additional `BloombergOutput` element at the top is retained; additionally, its `CreatedUtc` parameter is retained in a rather strange way.  My original intent was to remove the unnecessary `BloombergOutput` tags altogether.
2. I successfully inserted the addition of an `Instrument` tag. 
   However, `Instruments` is retained without me expressly saying so. 
   I get that the Identity Transform brought it along because I didn't
   tell it to go away, but what if I wanted different opening elements
   (say, `StockQuote`)?
3. My intention was to get good at using the Identity Transform. 
   However, I'm not certain that my match modification is the correct
   way to accomplish what I'm doing.

Overall, I'm looking for your expert advice on how to improve this.  Feel free to tell me that I'm trying to jam in a design pattern where it doesn't belong. :)

Thanks so much.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Good question, +1.

**Here is a simpler, shorter and more concise solution (no variables, no `xsl:choose` / `xsl:when` / `xsl:otherwise`, no `substring()`):**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
     xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
     <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>
     <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

     <xsl:template match="node()|@*">
         <xsl:copy>
           <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
         </xsl:copy>
     </xsl:template>

     <xsl:template match="BloombergOutput | Fields" priority="2">
      <xsl:apply-templates/>
     </xsl:template>

     <xsl:template match="*[starts-with(name(),'Field')]">
       <xsl:element name="{@Name}">
         <xsl:apply-templates/>
       </xsl:element>
     </xsl:template>

     <xsl:template match="Value">
      <xsl:apply-templates/>
     </xsl:template>

     <xsl:template match=
      "*[contains('|LastPrice|LastClosePrice|NetChangeOneDay|',
                  concat('|', @Name, '|')
                  )
        ]
          /Value
        ">

        <xsl:value-of select=
          "format-number(translate(.,'+', ''), '##0.00')"/>
     </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**When this transformation is applied to the provided XML document**:

```
<BloombergOutput>
  <BloombergOutput CreatedUtc="2011-08-11T20:40:50.8851936Z">
    <Instruments>
      <Instrument Symbol="BLL">
        <Fields>
          <Field1 Name="LastPrice">
            <Value>35.550000</Value>
          </Field1>
          <Field2 Name="NetChangeOneDay">
            <Value>+1.550000</Value>
          </Field2>
          <Field3 Name="LastCloseDate">
            <Value>08/11/2011</Value>
          </Field3>
          <Field4 Name="LastClosePrice">
            <Value>35.550000</Value>
          </Field4>
          <Field5 Name="UpdateDate">
            <Value>08/11/2011</Value>
          </Field5>
          <Field6 Name="UpdateTime">
            <Value>16:15:03</Value>
          </Field6>
          <Field7 Name="LongName">
            <Value>Ball Corp</Value>
          </Field7>
          <Field8 Name="Name">
            <Value>BALL CORP</Value>
          </Field8>
          <Field9 Name="PriceSource">
            <Value>US</Value>
          </Field9>
          <Field10 Name="SymbolType">
            <Value>Common Stock</Value>
          </Field10>
        </Fields>
      </Instrument>
    </Instruments>
  </BloombergOutput>
</BloombergOutput>
```

**the wanted, correct result is produced**:

```
<Instruments>
   <Instrument Symbol="BLL">
      <LastPrice>35.55</LastPrice>
      <NetChangeOneDay>1.55</NetChangeOneDay>
      <LastCloseDate>08/11/2011</LastCloseDate>
      <LastClosePrice>35.55</LastClosePrice>
      <UpdateDate>08/11/2011</UpdateDate>
      <UpdateTime>16:15:03</UpdateTime>
      <LongName>Ball Corp</LongName>
      <Name>BALL CORP</Name>
      <PriceSource>US</PriceSource>
      <SymbolType>Common Stock</SymbolType>
   </Instrument>
</Instruments>
```

Comment: Thanks, @Dimitre. I like your thinking. However, two notes: (1) when I run this transform (using xsltproc), I get an xsl:element: The effective name '' is not a valid QName. error regarding the {@Name} value; (2) It looks like for some fields, there's still a value element - my intention was to get rid of those and have the value be directly output.

Comment: @ABach: Good catch. I haven't noticed this because Saxon 6.5.4 (XSLT 1.0 processor) has a bug and the transformation succeeds. Now I ran it with Saxon 9.1.05 (XSLT 2.0 processor). I'll update my answer shortly. Just use: `     <xsl:template match="BloombergOutput | Fields" priority="2">` instead of `     <xsl:template match="BloombergOutput | Fields" >`
`

Comment: Thank you - that solves that issue.  What about the last one (wherein there are extraneous `<value>` elements that I want to remove)?  I would like all fields to follow the format of `<LastPrice>` (rather than, say, `<SymbolType>`).  I appreciate your help.

Comment: @ABach: I am at work right now -- please, be patient -- I will look into this 5-6 hours from now.

Comment: @ABach: Is my understanding correct that you want to have: `<SymbolType>Common Stock</SymbolType>` and *not*: `<SymbolType><Value>Common Stock</Value></SymbolType> `

Comment: sorry for the delay - yes, that understanding is correct.  No rush - thanks so much.

Comment: @ABach: OK, I assume you want the same format uniformly accross the result document. Based on this assumption (you never showed us what exactly the wanted result should be!), I modified my answer with a new transformation that produces what I assume is the wanted result.

Comment: That's it!  Thanks so much.  Apologies for not specifically labeling the block in the original post as "This Is What I Want" - I'll make sure to get there next time. :)

Answer (score 3):

I think that here is the mechanism you're looking for :

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
    xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="no" indent="yes"/>
    <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

    <!-- Get rid of the BloombergOutput, Instruments elements-->
    <xsl:template match="BloombergOutput|Instruments">
        <xsl:apply-templates/>
    </xsl:template>
    <!-- Identity Transform -->
    <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <!-- For each instrument, we grab the Symbol attribute and work on each child element -->
    <xsl:template match="Instrument">
        <Instrument>
            <Symbol><xsl:value-of select="@Symbol" /></Symbol>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="Fields/*" />
        </Instrument>
    </xsl:template>

    <!-- For each child field, we create a newly-named one and give it a value -->
    <xsl:template match="*[starts-with(name(),'Field')]">

        <xsl:variable
            name="FieldName"
            select="@Name" />
        <xsl:variable
            name="Value"
            select="Value" />

        <xsl:element name="{$FieldName}">
            <xsl:choose>
                <!-- For these fields, we only want to preserve to spots after the decimal point -->
                <xsl:when test="$FieldName='LastPrice' or $FieldName='NetChangeOneDay' or $FieldName='LastClosePrice'">
                    <xsl:value-of select="concat(substring-before($Value, '.'), '.', substring(substring-after($Value, '.'), 1, 2))" />
                </xsl:when>
                <xsl:otherwise>
                    <xsl:value-of select="$Value" />
                </xsl:otherwise>
            </xsl:choose>
        </xsl:element>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Note that you don't have to change the identity template. The goal of this template is to say : whenever you don't know what to do, stay with what already exists.

For the rest, in your case you don't need mode, you just need :

1. For elements like `Instruments` or `BloombergOutput` : continue without creating any kind of structure
2. do specific tasks for elements that start with `Field`.

The result is :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Instrument>
   <Symbol>BLL</Symbol>
   <LastPrice>35.55</LastPrice>
   <NetChangeOneDay>+1.55</NetChangeOneDay>
   <LastCloseDate>08/11/2011</LastCloseDate>
   <LastClosePrice>35.55</LastClosePrice>
   <UpdateDate>08/11/2011</UpdateDate>
   <UpdateTime>16:15:03</UpdateTime>
   <LongName>Ball Corp</LongName>
   <Name>BALL CORP</Name>
   <PriceSource>US</PriceSource>
   <SymbolType>Common Stock</SymbolType>
</Instrument>
```

One more remark, if you have two `Instrument` elements, the result of the transform won't be well formed.

Comment: Thanks for your reply.  Question: why will multiple `Instrument` elements result in a non-well-formed result?

Comment: When you match the Instruments element, you only have apply-templates. That means that for each Instrument child, the template Instrument will be fired, without any englobing element. You can add a test (with xsl:choose) to the template : if count(*)>1 then create an englobing element and apply-templates in it, else just apply-templates.